# Limit in app purchase devices count

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, limit, restrict

I'm about to do a partnership to propose some content in an Android app through in-app purchases. My partner wants that a purchase can be used on 5 devices maximum. Isn't that against the in-app purchase rules (a purchase should be available on all the user's devices)? It is against Apple ones, but I can't find any relevant information for Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it >< ... Here (section 3.8):

http://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html